# Re-parenting GUI Objects

Tags: matlab

How can I transfer GUI objects (buttons, sliders, lists, etc...) back and forth between 2 figures, while maintaining their functionality (callbacks and interactions)? In other words, transfer all the objects from figure 1 to figure 2, and have them execute their scripts as they have on figure 1.

Comment: Use the `Parent` property of uicontrols: `set( your_object_Handle , 'Parent' , destination_figure_handle )`. If they need to grab data from the new figure to execute the script/function you'll have to be careful to pick the right data tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to manage how you set up your uicontrols and your callbacks work, and to use the legacy switch in copyobj as ["un"documented here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/copyobj-behavior-change-in-hg2)

The example below allows you to reparent a **copy** of all your objects from figure to figure - I appreciate this is not "transferring" but copying -> but they all still work independently...

```
function test_reparentObjects
  % Create a new figure
  f1 = figure ( 'Name', 'Original Figure' );
  % Create some objects - make sure they ALL have UNIQUE tags - this is important!!
  axes ( 'parent', f1, 'tag', 'ax' );
  uicontrol ( 'style', 'pushbutton', 'position', [0   0 100 25], 'string', 'plot',     'parent', f1, 'callback', {@pb_cb}, 'tag', 'pb' );
  uicontrol ( 'style', 'pushbutton', 'position', [100 0 100 25], 'string', 'reparent', 'parent', f1, 'callback', {@reparent}, 'tag', 'reparent' );
  uicontrol ( 'style', 'text',       'position', [300 0 100 25], 'string', 'no peaks', 'parent', f1, 'tag', 'txt' );
  uicontrol ( 'style', 'edit',       'position', [400 0 100 25], 'string', '50',       'parent', f1, 'callback', {@pb_cb}, 'tag', 'edit' );
end
function pb_cb(obj,event)
  % This is a callback for the plot button being pushed
  % find the parent figure
  h = ancestor ( obj, 'figure' );
  % from the figure find the axes and the edit box
  ax  = findobj ( h, 'tag', 'ax' );
  edt = findobj ( h, 'tag', 'edit' );
  % convert the string to a double
  nPeaks = str2double ( get ( edt, 'string' ) );
  % do the plotting
  cla(ax)
  [X,Y,Z] = peaks(nPeaks);
  surf(X,Y,Z);
end 
function reparent(obj,event)
  % This is a callback for reparenting all the objects
  currentParent = ancestor ( obj, 'figure' );
  % copy all the objects -> using the "legacy" switch (r2014b onwards)
  %  this ensures that all callbacks are retained
  children = copyobj ( currentParent.Children, currentParent, 'legacy' );
  % create a new figure
  f = figure ( 'Name', sprintf ( 'Copy of %s', currentParent.Name ) );
  % reparent all the objects that have been copied
  for ii=1:length(children)
    children(ii).Parent = f;
  end
end
```